# Can you change the processing extent in environment settings using python to a shapefile?

Tags: python, raster, arcgis-10.1, extents

I have managed to do this manually at Geoprocessing>Environments>Processing Extent and setting the shapefile in the drop down bar.

I was wonder if this could be automated with a python script?

My goal is to create a loop to change the processing extent prior to using spatial analysis tools on a various rasters that represent the areas of the shapefiles. This will keep their extent size minimal.

Edit (Current Code): (Not working)

```
for i in range (31):
... arcpy.env.extent = (r"C:\Folder\Shapefile"+str(i)+".shp")
```

Receiving a runtime error stating "Error in accessing environment "

Comment: so I don't define what str (i) is?

Comment: You already defined  `i` in your `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As per the the [extent help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000009000000), set `arcpy.env.extent = 'path to shapefile'` (assuming ArcGIS 10+ as you didn't specify). Don't forget to set the [Snap Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000000m000000) environment so your output raster isn't shifted.

Comment: I set my extent in a loop and received the runtimeerror: error in accessing environment <extent> Here is my code: for i in range (31): ... arcpy.env.extent = (r"E:\data\Shapefile"+str(i)) Is something stated wrong here?

Comment: you are missing the + ".shp" after str(i)

Comment: @radouxju: I've added the +".shp" after str (i). Still giving the same error. I'll post the code as an edit in the question.

Comment: Took a break from attempting this. Tried again with the same code, worked fine. No idea what was wrong before.

Answer (score 2):

here is another approach, with some test in the loop to help you identify if something goes wrong :

```
import arcpy

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("C:\\folder\\Shapefile_root*") #shapefile_root is the start of the name of your shapefile

for fc in fcs:
    print fc #just checking that you are looping on the good shp
    arcpy.env.extent = fc
    print arcpy.env.extent # checking that the extent is updated
    ...
```

Comment: I haven't managed to get this code to work. When i type fc, it trys to autocomplete it to fcs. Nothing prints

Comment: what do you have when you type "fcs" (it should be an object) ? Is your indentation in the "for" loop correct ?

Comment: you should try copying this script and launching it as a stand alone. Make sure that your path is correct (once it is E, once it is C in your question)